installed near and got usb lib error, what is the trouble?
I installed near over WSL setting.
Linux NT00654071 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #3996-Microsoft Thu Jan 18 16:36:00 PST 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
node and npm versions are fine. I changed default npm directory before installation.
npm install -g near-cli
npm warn deprecated base-x@2.0.6: use 3.0.0 instead, safe-buffer has been merged and release for compatability
npm warn deprecated @ledgerhq/hw-transport-u2f@5.36.0-deprecated: @ledgerhq/hw-transport-u2f is deprecated. Please use @ledgerhq/hw-transport-webusb or @ledgerhq/hw-transport-webhid. https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs/blob/master/docs/migrate_webusb.md
changed 240 packages in 1m
when I try near --help I get this error. could you please help me?
* near --help*
**Failed to initialize libusb.**
/home/igor/.nvm/versions/node/v22.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/usb/dist/usb/index.js:30
    Object.defineProperty(usb.Device.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(device_1.ExtendedDevice.prototype, name) || Object.create(null));
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at /home/igor/.nvm/versions/node/v22.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/usb/dist/usb/index.js:30:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igor/.nvm/versions/node/v22.6.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/usb/dist/usb/index.js:29:63)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:12)

Node.js v22.6.0

I tried to install near and I get libusb initialization error. I expected near to work fine.

When you say near do you mean installing near CLI?
Try installing the pre built binaries

curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -LsSf
https://github.com/near/near-cli-rs/releases/download/v0.15.1/near-cli-rs-installer.sh
| sh

https://github.com/near/near-cli-rs/releases/tag/v0.15.1
